# Is it fine to split data of one table even though it has one to one relation?

Tags: mysql, database-design

We have used commodities website where sellers upload their commodities and buyers can see their contact after registering their mobile number on our website. Every such lead/transaction where buyer takes seller details gets stored in Leads table that looks like:

```
LeadId | CustomerId
LeadId: Primary, Auto-increment key of this table.

CustomerId: Foreign key of CustomerTable.
```

Now we want to track which lead came from which source. For this we need several tracking parameters like: `sourceId, campaignID, platformId..` and several others"

Though lead and these tracking parameters have one to one relation but does it make sense to keep them together OR we should have separate table for these:
Example: LeadTracking table which will have all these tracking parameters.

Note: This is over simplified example. We actually have several Lead and LeadTracking columns.

Can we keep them in separate tables? How should we decide when to split such tables?

Comment: You created a website to which people can upload their entire car? That's awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Logically* the tracking columns can probably all be in leads table (based on your description of them as 1-1).

You can implement the data structure using one or two tables; that is an implementation decision.

Why would you do this?  Here are some reasons:

- If many of the leads do not have tracking information, why bother having lots of empty columns?  Such columns can both confuse users and take up extra space on the data pages.
- If the tracking columns are particularly wide (or numerous), then the extra space can affect the performance of queries that do not use them.
- If the tracking columns are frequently updated, then having them in a separate table can help prevent locking from slowing down queries.
- If the tracking columns might be changing but the leads columns are stable, then you might want to isolate the columns to a table that is more likely to change.
- If the tracking columns have different security requirements, it is easier to specify security on a table basis than on a column basis.

No doubt, there are other reasons as well.  When I learned this process it was called "vertical partitioning", because the tables "split" the original data by columns (vertically) rather than by rows (horizontally).